# Kubuntu 18.04 on Mac, how to activate wifi?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet, broadcom, mac

I apologize if this is a silly question, but how do I tell my firmware to recognize the wifi hardware?

I have limited experience with Linux and not terribly familiar with Mac. My inlaws gave us a Mac, nice machine, but I don't like OSX. I made a flash drive and replaced OSX with Kubuntu 18.04. I have not had too much trouble with it, other than that I cannot get the wifi figured out for the life of me. I had to manually configure the ethernet connection as well, but that was much easier to muddle through. I have tried to manually configure the wifi also, under System Settings>Connections. It allows me to enter the information and save the connection, but it does not actually work at all.

The short version of what I tried: `lspci` shows network device Broadcom 802.11 etc, so it recognizes the actual hardware exists.

`lshw -class network` shows the same device.

`rfkill list all` only shows bluetooth (not blocked), does not reflect the wireless network device at all.

See below for details.

I did these:

```
sudo lshw -class network
lspci
rfkill list all
```

Results: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/tbdz2tjzH9/

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:b1a00000-b1a07fff memory:b1800000-b19fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 0c:4d:e9:99:2b:5a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=57766a-v1.15 ip=192.168.1.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:b1b00000-b1b0ffff memory:b1b10000-b1b1ffff
```

and

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
04:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
```

the result of

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth                                                                                            
        Soft blocked: no                                                                                              
        Hard blocked: no
```

On another thread, it was recommended that I run this script:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

Resulting text file pasted here:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Fxhmdpv6sT/

I think I am missing something. I am going to try to install network manager I guess, based on the script in the second link it appears that is missing. I'm flying from the seat of my pants here. Any assistance would be very greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your last two links you are pasting the source code for the scripts you ran, not the output from the scripts. I don't have the Broadcom WiFi but you can search here and find lots of questions and answers about "BCM" (the broadcom adapter). You can get a blue Ethernet cable and plug it in between your laptop and your router to skip the whole WiFi thing until you get it working.

Comment: ok thank you, and I will check again. Like I said, noob here :) I have been browsing these threads for two days, and trying different things - and the ethernet is fine. I just need to get this mac out of the living room and back into the office! Its not a laptop, it is an all-in-ine desktop and the wire running across the room is cumbersome. Ill update if and when I figure it out and post what I did.

Comment: Yeah cables are cumbersome. I bought a 25 footer just so it goes from the coffee table behind the couch and along the bottom of three walls to the router. You can buy them up to 300 feet long.

Comment: I am absolutely thrilled, finally got it!!! This is what I did, for reference if anyone else stumbles on this and has this issue with a Mac or PC with broadcom wifi hardware (in the computer).

I did these 3 things:

sudo apt-get autoremove bcmwl-kernel-source                                                                                                                                                                                                                

sudo apt-get --purge remove bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: You can take your comment and use it to answer your own question. Then accept it in two days. Then others will know what works... Congrats :)